# Advanced Custom Fields Order By Meta Key value

Tags: php, wordpress, get, advanced-custom-fields, posts

I have a simple Wordpress query that lists my custom post type results.

Currently, they list in order of date the post was created.

I need them to **list in the order of a custom field I have named 'release_year'** from most recent to oldest.

I am having trouble incorporating that second query to my results.

How do I ensure all posts are sorted by release_year ??

ANy help appreciated.

```
<?php 
  $posts = get_posts(array(
  'post_type'           => 'discography',
  'posts_per_page'      => -1,
  'meta_key'            => 'release_category',
  'meta_value'          => 'album',
  'orderby'             => 'meta_value',
  'order'               => 'ASC',
  ));            
if( $posts ): ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to order by `release_year` however you're specifying `release_category` as the meta key therefore it has no way of knowing that you want to use the other key instead.

The main issue you face is you can't have two `meta_key` args. Instead you need to make use of the `meta_query` argument.

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
   'post_type'           => 'discography',
   'posts_per_page'      => -1,
   'meta_key'            => 'release_year',
   'orderby'             => 'meta_value_num',
   'order'               => 'DESC',
   'meta_query'          => array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'release_category',
            'value' => 'album',
        ),
    ),
));
```

The meta query is used to set the release category and the `meta_key` value changed to the key you'd like to order by. I've also set order to `meta_value_num` which is important when dealing with numerical values. Finally you need to use descending order.

Further reading: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: Thanks so much Nathan - this worked perfectly. The explanation was great as well.